# Geometric Construction : Construct a Triangle given 3 heights ..

Tags: geometry, triangles, geometric-construction

Given 3 heights : $h_1=5\mathrm{cm}$ ; $h_2=7\mathrm{cm}$ ; $h_3=8\mathrm{cm}$ ... It is required to draw that triangle using only compass and ruler !

**N.B.:** *It is not allowed to calculate the area then the sides: the measure of the sides won't be exact.*

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Given the heights (and an arbitrary "unit" length) we can construct lengths $\frac1{h_1}$, $\frac1{h_2}$, $\frac1{h_3}$. Construct a triangle $APQ$ with $PQ=\frac1{h_1}$, $AQ=\frac1{h_2}$, $AP=\frac1{h_3}$.
This triangle has heights $h_A\sim h_1$, $h_P\sim h_2$, $h_Q\sim h_3$.
All we need is to scale appropriately.
Let $g$ be the line through $A$ perpendicular to $PQ$. Find $R$ on $g$ with $AR=h_1$. The line through $R$ perpendicular to $g$ (or equivalently: parallel to $PQ$) intersects $AP$ in $B$ and $AQ$ in $C$. Then in triangle $ABC$ we have $h_A=h_1$, $h_B=h_2$, $h_C=h_3$.

Comment: Two pairs fit, but the third one doesn't. $($Yes, I've tried both cases$).$ I believe there's some small typo somewhere in your answer.

Comment: @Lucian I simplified the construction so much that I should not be able to have messed things up :)

Comment: I wonder why this topic is closed. I made out a construction out of the instructions by Hagen although using altitudes of an arbitrary triangle. I was searching for this problem here after the book gave a weird hint.